# Interpolation of martingale

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis

Consider a non-constant martingale $(M_n)_{n\ge 0}$ with the filtration $(\mathcal{F}_n)_{n\ge 0}$, where $\mathcal{F}_n=\sigma(M_m:m\le n)$.

Define  for $t\in\mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}$:

$$X_t:=M_{\lfloor t\rfloor}+(t-\lfloor t\rfloor)(M_{\lceil t\rceil}-M_{\lfloor t\rfloor})$$

How does the natural filtration $(\mathcal{A}_t)_{t\ge 0}$ with $\mathcal{A}_t=\sigma(X_s:s\le t)$ look like? And is $X=(X_t)_{t\ge 0}$ a martingale with respect to $(\mathcal{A}_t)_{t\ge 0}$? Any help or hint will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have any thoughts on the problem? What have you tried....?

Comment: $X_t^{-1}(-\infty, a)=\bigcup_{r,s\in\mathbb{Q}, r+s<a}\big((1-\lfloor t\rfloor +t)M_{\lfloor t\rfloor}\big)^{-1}(-\infty, r)\cap\big((\lfloor t\rfloor -t)M_{\lceil t\rceil}\big)^{-1}(-\infty, s)$ which is in $\mathcal{F}_{\lceil t \rceil}$. So we have $\sigma(X_s:s\le t)=\mathcal{F}_{\lceil t\rceil}$. Is this right?

Comment: So I find it is no martingale, since $E[X_t|G_s]=E[X_t|F_{\lceil s\rceil}]=(1-\lfloor t\rfloor +t)M_{\lceil s\rceil}+(t-\lfloor t \rfloor)M_{\lceil s \rceil}=M_{\lceil s \rceil}$ for $s\le\lfloor t \rfloor$, but I think if you want to interpolate a martingale you still want to get back a martingale...

Comment: Yeah you are right that it is no martingale and also you are right about the filtration.

Comment: Ok, this seems like an counter-intuitive example to me. :-) Thank you again for replying, saz!